# Is it possible to modify style using Cucumber + Capybara?

Tags: css, ruby, capybara

So I have the scenario where I want to demonstrate to the business how Cucumber can be of benefit. It's easy to setup a demo and run but, without the proper visuals, the business won't really see the benefit... question is: is it possible to add a CSS class whilst the feature is being executed?

Something like this:

```
anchor = page.find_link(link);
anchor[:style].value = 'outline:yellow solid thick';
sleep 1;
click_link(link);
```

What I'm not sure is the second line. How can I achieve an `outline style` on an element that is about to be clicked?

I couldn't find anything similar on the actual Cucumber spec. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

Ok I found a solution: execute a script to modify the CSS.

```
page.execute_script("$('selector').css('property','value')");
```

Works quite well :-)